# Problem using Get-Help from within PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, command-line

It must be something extremely simple but I just can't make `Get-Help` work from within my PowerShell script.

- When I run `Get-Help myscript -Examples` in PowerShell command window, I get perfect help message. However,
- When I call `Get-Help myscript -Examples` in my PowerShell script, it runs as if that the `-Examples` is not specified -- the normal help is shown, instead of the examples help.

**UPDATE:**

As @lit has suspect, the reason is that, I'm running Get-Help on the same script that is currently running.

I just want to show help message for for my script. Here is an example you can try out:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS

Calculates the number of possible passwords

.DESCRIPTION

Calculates the number of possible passwords based
on the input so you will know the actual number before
you proceed to create your dictionary file.

.PARAMETER CharacterSet

Specifies the characters (letters, numbers, symbols) that
need to be included. Parameter is mandatory.

.PARAMETER MinCharacters

Specifies the minimum characters of the generated passwords.
Parameter is mandatory.

.PARAMETER MaxCharacters

Specifies the maximum characters of the generated passwords.
Parameter is mandatory.

.PARAMETER IncludeCapital

Specifies whether or not to include upper case letters along with
the lower case letters.

.PARAMETER CapitalOnly

Specifies whether or not all lower case letters to be converted to
upper case letters.

.INPUTS

System.String. Get-PasswordNumber can accept a string value to
determine the CharacterSet parameter.

.OUTPUTS

System.Double. Get-PasswordNumber returns the number of passwords that
can be created.

.EXAMPLE

C:\PS> Get-PasswordNumber -CharacterSet "a,b,c,1,2,3,$,*,&" -MinCharacters 2 -MaxCharacters 5
66420

.EXAMPLE

C:\PS> Get-PasswordNumber -Characters "a,b,c,1,2,3,$,*,&" -MinCharacters 2 -MaxCharacters 5 -IncludeCapital
271440

.EXAMPLE

C:\PS> Get-PasswordNumber -Characters "a,b,c,1,2,3,$,*,&" -MinCharacters 2 -MaxCharacters 5 -CapitalOnly
66420

.EXAMPLE

C:\PS> Get-PasswordNumber -Characters alphabet -MinCharacters 2 -MaxCharacters 5
12356604

.LINK

PowerShell Module DictionaryFile
#>


param(
        [switch]$IncludeCapital,
        [switch]$CapitalOnly)

write-host program started.

if (!$CapitalOnly) {
  Get-Help myscript
  Get-Help myscript -Examples

}

write-host program ended.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: use `Out-String` as follows:

```
Get-Help $MyInvocation.InvocationName -Examples | Out-String
```

**In detail**:

- found that **described behaviour appears for any valid cmdlet / function /script** name in place of `myscript` in

> *when I call `Get-Help myscript -Examples` in my PowerShell script, it runs as if that the `-Examples` is not specified*

- found an innocent (however supposedly unrelated) note in [`Get-Help Get-Help -Online`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help):

> Because the `Get-Help` cmdlet generates a `MamlCommandHelpInfo`
>   object, not a string, you have to use a cmdlet that transforms the
>   help topic content into a string, such as `Out-String` or `Out-File`.

- unsuccessfully sniffed in [`MamlCommandHelpInfo.cs`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/help/MamlCommandHelpInfo.cs) for differences in using `Get-Help` from within a `.ps1` script vs. PS prompt.